# Simple partial derivatives chain rule proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $z=f(x,y)$, suppose $x=s+t$ and $y=s-t$ show that

$(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2 - (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^2=\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$

I have rearranged to get them both in terms of s but this hasn't yielded any success. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you can easily solve for $s$ and $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ to get $s = \frac{x+y}{2}$ and $t = \frac{x-y}{2}$. Now you can use the chain rule to evaluate the left-hand side of your equation, involving $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

(as $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}=1, \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=1$) and

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

(as $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=1, \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=-1$).

Multiply those two equalities above to reach the desired equality.

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment above, you can solve to get $s = \frac{x+y}{2}$ and $t = \frac{x-y}{2}$. Now use the chain rule to evaluate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$. You can see from the equations above that $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{\partial s}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{\partial t}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{2}$.

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \right) $$

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} - \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \right) $$

Now plug these expressions into the left-hand side of your equation. From here on out, I'm going to use the notations $z_s$ and $z_t$ instead of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$, to make typing easier.

$$ \begin {align*} z_x^2 - z_y^2 &= \frac{1}{4} (z_s+z_t)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(z_s-z_t)^2 \\ &= \frac{1}{4} (z_s^2 + 2z_sz_t + z_t^2) - \frac{1}{4} (z_s^2 - 2z_sz_t + z_t^2) \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \left( z_s^2 + 2z_sz_t + z_t^2 - z_s^2 + 2z_sz_t - z_t^2 \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{4} \left( 4z_sz_t \right) \\ &= z_s z_t \end{align*} $$